# Webpacker does not detect imported functions in file javascript/packs/application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have this function in file dashboard.js

```
var Dashboard = function(){

 return {
   init: function(){
     console.log("Hi from Dashboard with webpacker")
   }
 }
}();
```

with webpacker I'm importing as this in file javascript/packs/application.js

```
import '../src/api/dashboard.js';
```

but when I want to use the init function in a view as this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Dashboard.init();
  });
</script>
```

I got the error

```
 (index):861 Uncaught ReferenceError: Dashboard is not defined
  at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):861)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I also tried imported file as this

```
import Dashboard from '../src/api/dashboard.js';
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I know you asked this question like 5 months ago, and I am not a JS expert (yet), so this may not be the be optimal (nor cleanest) solution. But anyway, I had the same issue and here's how I cope with it.

Before adding Webpacker, this function was triggered by button's click (and it was working just fine):

```
function validateFile(inputFile) {
  ..
}
```

But after adding Webpacker I got `Uncaught ReferenceError` just like you. Now it looks like this:

```
window.validateFile = function(inputFile) {
  ..
}
```

And it worked like a charm!

Hope that helps you, and if not - then somebody else :)

Comment: This worked for me with Rails 6! Thank you!